# Amfphp is working slow with Flex-4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, amfphp

Well,
I am trying to use remote object (Amfphp) in a project which is using httpservice. I heard it will make my application faster. But when i tried Amfphp in a datagrid for testing purpose i found it takes even more time then httpservice. Here is what i have done so far.

AS-3 code to call php function:

```
public function init():void{
            var params:Array = new Array();
            params.push("1234");
            _amf = new RemoteObject;
            _amf.destination = "dummyDestination";
            _amf.endpoint = "http://insight2.ultralysis.com/Amfphp/Amfphp/";//http://insight2.ultralysis.com
            _amf.source = "manager1";                       
            _amf.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, handleResult);
            _amf.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, handleFault);
            _amf.init(params);

        }

        public function handleResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
            myGrid.dataProvider = event.result.grid;
        }
```

And the php function to fetch data from mysql database:

```
class output{
public $grid;
public $week;
}

function form()
{

    $arrayOut = new output();
    $arrayOut->grid = $this->gridValue();
    $arrayOut->week= $this->getAllWeek($this->ThisYear);
    return $arrayOut;
```

}

Everything works fine. But it takes almost 5 seconds to fetch and render 280 rows of data.
Can anyone please help me make it as fast as it should ? I've already tried the optimization tips of [silexlabs](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/optimizing-amfphp)

I used packet sniffer and stats are the following. It says Latency is consuming most of the time about 5 sec. What's that latency? Need help guys. Please:

[image]

Comment: ooops !! i forgot to mention the amfphp version i'm using. It's Amfphp 2.0

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is slow because of the AMF serialization or something else.  I'd try to add clock outputs as it goes through that function to see if there is any slowdown in the database stuff.  If not then it is possible that AMFPHP is just very slow.

Comment: thanks for the reply James Ward. I've tried clock outputs. It takes 400 ms in service browser of amfphp and the same function with same parameters takes 7/8 seconds in flex application.

Comment: So is that mostly spent in AMF serialization, network transfer, or AMF deserialization?  You can do more manual instrumentation to find this out.

Comment: okey. Can you please help me doing more manual instrumentation ? I am thinking about packet sniffing. But i don't know how to do that. A little help would be appreciated :)

Comment: well i managed to use packet sniffer. (It was easy :D). Based on the packet sniffer result i think the main culprit is "Latency". So how can i reduce that ? Any ideas please ????

Comment: Latency doesn't really describe where the problem actually is.  I'm not sure how to instrument AMFPHP to get the serialization time.  But you can look at the Census code to see an example of how to instrument the network transfer and deserialization.  https://github.com/jamesward/census2-tests/blob/master/client/flex/src/flex_amf3.mxml

Comment: Thank you very much james ward for your kind help. I'm gonna try the idea of AmfPacket and test the app if it runs faster. But please be there if i need some more suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `amfphp 1.9`.

`amfphp 2.x` version is unfortunately slower than `1.9`